# Bash_profile doesn’t work

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I want use `.bash_profile` but I have a bug.

In my file I have :

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But When my `JAVA_HOME` is called by `Ionic` I have :

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I don't know why my `JAVA_HOME` is not same.

I try to launch `. .bash_profile` but don't work

Comment: you should try 'source .bash_profile'  The file is probably not executable. Or open a new terminal window.

Comment: @jmh the dot is the same as `source`

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `~/.bash_profile` please.  Also, start a new session and post the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: i put an echo statement in all my profiles, so that I know which ones have run.

Answer (score 2):

Per memory in the `.bash_profile` when I used to dabble in Java you need to add export and ". In the Terminal run the command:

```
 nano .bash_profile
```

Then add:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Then do the reboot of: `. .bash_profile` after you've saved the `bash_profile`

Answer (score 1):

Bash uses its various rc files differently depending on how it's invoked.  Read the INVOCATION section of the bash man page for the specifics but briefly for a login shell it will read bash_profile (along with other things), and for a non-login shell, it will read bashrc (along with other things).  Most people will source bashrc from their bash_profile and do everything else in bashrc.

You don't show it, but presumably you're not export-ing JAVA_HOME.  You should.  You want to make sure that goes to the parent shell.